# answer incoming call with AMI / AGI

Tags: asterisk, pbx, asteriskami, agi

I am working in a cti student project with asterisk , thanks to the AMI I could initiate a 
     call , hold call and unhold call but I need to answer incoming call :

for example an external call is coming to SIP/test thanks to the event NewStateEvent i know

the name of the channel calling and the channel requested but I want to answer the call via

IHM WITH click to the button for example , I searched in internet it's not possible via AMI

Comment: Perhaps this will help to clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836466/asterisk-ami-pickup-call/10838288#10838288

Comment: Yes i tried it but i dont handle any AsyncAGIEvent when i call peer test from another peer :/

Comment: And i put the line exten => _X.,1,AGI(agi:async) in my dialplan , when i connect from java app to the server via AMI i i make call between peers no AsyncAgiEvent handled help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use agi you just need use some lib and do answer or just sent one line "ANSWER"

If you use AMI, you have transfer call to some dialplan which will answer call.

Anyway it is highly recomended read FULL book and understand how dialplan work.

Comment: When i transfert call , the caller channel hungup and the called chennel still ring , with AGI i get unable to send SIGHUP to AGI process 3893: No such process from the server !!!!!

Comment: Please read doc for transfer. Called channel have be trasnfered to other extension. I am sorry, can say nothing about AGI. Consult selected language docs.