# Answer call from php with AGI and AMI

Tags: php, asterisk, voip, agi

Just I need to write `exten => 116,2,AGI(agi:async)` in dialplan????

I did know that I should write an agi file in folder `/usr/bin`

Sorry but I have never create an AGI

Thanks

[Asterisk ami/agi - not able to answer call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356491/asterisk-ami-agi-not-able-to-answer-call/25925075?noredirect=1#comment40583909_25925075)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest agi script is

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ANSWER"
echo "STREAM \"somefile\" "
```

For more info see http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI

There are alot of library for any common languages availible.

Async AGI just put call on hold, after that you have do any action using AMI. It is NOT simple. So try first usual AGI scripts.